# удаление первого листа из всех документов ворд в папке

Tags: vba, ms-word

есть куча (9000) документов word в папке. Нужно удалить из всех первую страницу (желательно без изменения нумерации, но можно просто удалить). Есть код:

```
Sub porn()
Dim sFolder As String, sFiles As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
sFolder = sFolder & IIf(Right(sFolder, 1) = Application.PathSeparator, "", 
Application.PathSeparator)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sFiles = Dir(sFolder & "*.doc*")
Do While sFiles <> ""
Document.Open sFolder & sFiles
Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 1
Selection.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Delete
Document.Close True
sFiles = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

но он выдает ошибку "Run-time error '424'. Object required

В VBA совсем 0, можете подсказать?

Answer (score 1):

У класса `Document` нет метода `Open`.

Попробуйте открыть документ так:

```
Documents.Open FileName:="ПУТЬ_К_ФАЙЛУ"
```

А после редактирования сохранить его и закрыть, как активный документ, так:

```
ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close
```

Comment: А толку,если мне нужно проделать это с большим количеством файлов? он же на следующий цикл полезет опять в этот же файл?

Comment: Но Вы же на место пути к файлу подставляете значение переменных sFolder & sFiles, которые будут иметь разные значения на каждой итерации цикла. Проще говоря: `Documents.Open FileName:=sFolder & sFiles`

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало! Единственное что, есть еще вопрос: если документы запаролены, как указать пароль, чтобы он не всплывал каждый раз?

Comment: Указать пароль в параметре `PasswordDocument` при открытии файла. Пример: `Documents.Open FileName:="ФАЙЛ", PasswordDocument:="ПАРОЛЬ"`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код для Word, в случае если пригодится. Спасибо justcvb!

```
Sub Get_All_File_from_Folder()
Dim sFolder As String, sFiles As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
sFolder = sFolder & IIf(Right(sFolder, 1) = Application.PathSeparator, "", 
Application.PathSeparator)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sFiles = Dir(sFolder & "*.doc*")
Do While sFiles <> ""
Documents.Open FileName:=sFolder & sFiles
Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 1
Selection.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Delete
ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close
sFiles = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```